# Call XSL template as Iframe source

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSLT 1.0, is it possible to call an XSL template as the source of an iframe? Something along the lines of

```
<iframe src="foo/bar.xsl"></iframe>
```

If not, is there any way of pre-rendering the template into HTML via XSLT, and then appending the result as the source?

Comment: You can load an XML document associated with an XSLT stylesheet into your iframe and the browser will then transform the XML with the XSLT and render the result in the iframe. I don't understand what you want to achieve by solely loading an XSLT stylesheet into an iframe, you can do that of course but the browser is then likely to display the source of the XSLT in the iframe.

Comment: I'm in the process of documenting a component, and as part of that, there should be a working example embedded. I need to attach the example as an iframe, because it utilizes the entire web page, including the body tag. The example HTML is generated out of a XSL template